# Desktop shortcut yields different environment variables than command line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, desktop, shortcut

I have just installed a software package.  This package created a desktop shortcut to launch the software.  When I double click the shortcut it launches the software.  Within the software app interface it displays the value of %PATH%.

If I run the very same command as contained in the shortcut from a cmd.exe window then the value of %PATH% within the app is slightly different.  In the first case (the shortcut) there is an extra folder prepended to the path as compared to the second case of running from the command line.

I am racking my brain as to what would cause a shortcut to yield a different environment than a command line.  Does anyone have a theory as to what might cause this kind of behavior?  I have been researching windows shortcuts for some exotic capabilities that might be at play, but have found none.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is a special registry key described here.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx

The software I installed had an entry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths.  Within the key there was a string value named "Path".  This gets prepended when the shortcut is used.  Removing that Path value from the registry fixed this inconsistency.